# How do I make a utility method that compares the output of any sql query from two schemas

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

Suppose I have two schemas **TestSchema1** and **TestSchema2**. These two schemas have same tables and structure. Also, I have SQL queries as

```
Select * from table_one where table_field = 'xyz'.

Select * from table_two;
```

These two tables **table_one** and **table_two** can have any columns. However, table_one in schema TestSchema1 and TestSchema2 have the exact same structure(data can be different).

how do I create a utility method that compares the data from the SQL statement in two schemas? Something like:

```
public boolean isDataSameInBothSchemas(String query){
//logic to compare data
}
```

UPDATE: I also need to know the column in case of data mismatch so I cannot use 
 minus operation in database.

Comment: Which database you are using? Do not compare these tables at java side. Instead create a new sql query to compare them at database side.

Comment: I am using Oracle database. I also need to specify in which column the data does not match which I won't be able to do in database side.

Comment: You can also do it on database side. Just create a function that returns column name(like Mysql functions). Think that your tables have 10 gb of data and you need to compare them. What will you do? With your approach you need to send all these data to java side.

Comment: I know the limitation of this approach. I can compare data in batches in case of a large dataset using rowNumber limit. If I had to do it in java how do I  do that? I am having a problem with using jdbcTemplate when I don't know the columns.

Answer (score 0):

For oracle you can use

```
Select * from schema1.table_two
minus
Select * from schema2.table_two
```

If the query returns no rows the data is the same.

UPDATE:
The query must have no records as well.

```
Select * from schema2.table_two
minus
Select * from schema1.table_two
```

We need to subtract rows of table 1 from rows of table 2 and vice versa to be sure.

For java solution you need to introduce a `RowDTO` class to store row data for each query.

Then introduce `equals()` method for the `RowDTO` to compare objects.

Add both queries results to a `Set<RowDTO>`. (Could be e.g. HashSet).

After the queries you will have two sets accordingly.

```
Set<RowDTO> schema1Set;
Set<RowDTO> schema2Set;
```

You can use Set interface's methods

```
boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c);
boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c);
```

To find the difference and use remaining items to find what exactly is different.

If you need to find diff column then a custom util method to be introduced to compare field by field and show the different fields.

Comment: in case of data mismatch how do I know which column does not have matching data in this case?

Comment: Original question is about boolean - the same data or not. Comparing column by column is more complicated

Comment: `minus` is Oracle specific. For "standard SQL" that should be `except`